# Get 2 weeks of data from Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am returning a list of highest selling products. Currently my query brings back totals from the last 7 days worth of orders.

I also need to bring back the sum of the item qty for the previous 7 days, i would like to know how i would go about doing this? I was thinking that its simply adding 7 days onto the @startDate and 13 days to the @endDate (this already has the date set for 7 days after todays date)

currently getting the item qty in the **sum(amzOrdersItem.itemQty) AS Orders** line. This returns a count of the products orders essentially.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHighestSellingItems]
@startDate datetime, 
@endDate datetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT    TOP (20) twProducts.sku, 
          twProducts.title + ' /  ' + LTRIM(CAST(twProducts.strength AS varchar(15))) + '%' AS Title, 
          sum(amzOrdersItem.itemQty) AS Orders, 
          twProducts.stock, aboProducts.asin, aboProducts.amzPrice
FROM      twProducts INNER JOIN
          amzOrdersItem ON twProducts.sku = amzOrdersItem.productSku INNER JOIN
          amzOrders ON amzOrdersItem.amzOrderId = amzOrders.amzOrderId INNER JOIN
          aboProducts ON twProducts.sku = aboProducts.sku
where    (amzOrders.orderDate between @startDate and @endDate) and  amzOrders.cancelled = 0
          group by twProducts.sku, twProducts.title, twProducts.strength, 
          twProducts.stock, aboProducts.asin, aboProducts.amzPrice
ORDER BY sum(amzOrdersItem.itemQty) DESC
END
```

Thought this might be handy, this is .net code i am padding into the query, and getting results.

```
public List<GetHighSelling> GetHighSellingWeek()
    {
        DateTime? endDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime? startDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-6).Date;

        using (aboDataDataContext dc = new aboDataDataContext())
        {
            var query = from o in dc.GetHighestSellingItems(startDate, endDate)
                        select new GetHighSelling
                        {
                            sku = o.sku,
                            title = o.Title,
                            itemQty = o.Orders,
                            stock = o.stock,
                            amzPrice = o.amzPrice.ToString(),
                            asin = o.asin
                        };
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a question you wanted to ask?

Comment: this is the question... "i would like to know how i would go about doing this?"

I have it returning the count for the last 7 days, but i need it to return the count for the previous 7 days too :)

Comment: Do you understand any of this code at all?

Comment: of course, i wrote it! my .net code is my linq statement and populating my table. And the SQL is getting the data obviously. All i need to know is the best way to get the data for the week before the current week. I was thinking of adding 7 days onto @enddate in my query. But was unsure how to do it in the SQL. Or would it be worth doing it in  .NET. Thus why i asked, other people might know a better way of doing things.

Comment: @thatuxguy: In my opinion you should do that in the .NET code. The procedure is already neatly reusable so that you can get any interval you want. In .NET you can just make another method that sends a different interval to the procedure, or add a parameter to the method to tell it how many weeks ago you want to get.

Comment: How about Partitioning by week? Like that: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN amzOrders.orderDateBETWEEN @startDate AND (@startDate+6) THEN 1 WHEN amzOrders.orderDateBETWEEN (@startDate+7) AND @endDate THEN 2 END ORDER BY Sum(amzordersitem.itemqty) DESC)`, and that selection row numbers from 1 to 20 (40 records)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-13).Date;
```

Comment: So call it twice with two different parameters (-13 to -7), (-6 to 0)

Comment: and make them nullable in my stored procedure. I think thats the best option

Answer (score 1):

You should subtract seven days. If you add seven days, you will be asking for the highest selling products for one week into the future.

(Although that would be extremely useful information, the database isn't capable of seeing into the future. ;)

You can calculate the start date from the end date:

```
DateTime? endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
DateTime? startDate = endDate.AddDays(-6);
```

Comment: Not sure where I said i wanted future counts, I was asking for previous counts. I already have it doing the last 7 days, i now need 7 days before those 7 days lol :)

Comment: @thatuxguy: I meant that your query will ask for the records from the future.

Comment: @thatuxguy: Yes. As the query is getting the records from one week ago until now, adding seven days to the dates would get the records from now and one week into the future.

Comment: lol i see what you mean *facepalm* I mean i need to get 1st and 2nd week before todays date lol